# Using facet_wrap with multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data frame `WetNmaPso`

```
   Saison Site Category    NbWB_m2  NbWP_m2 mean_PercentCover
2     Wet   SW  CCA_Nma 19.3333333 7.000000       0.072833333
4     Wet   SW  CCA_Pso  0.8333333 0.000000       0.002500000
18    Wet   BY  CCA_Nma  0.0000000 2.666667       0.001166667
20    Wet   BY  CCA_Pso  3.1666667 1.333333       0.007666667
34    Wet   WF  CCA_Nma  3.5000000 3.333333       0.010333333
36    Wet   WF  CCA_Pso  0.0000000 0.000000       0.000000000
50    Wet   MP  CCA_Nma  0.1666667 0.500000       0.004666667
52    Wet   MP  CCA_Pso  0.0000000 0.000000       0.000000000
66    Wet   PK  CCA_Nma  0.0000000 0.000000       0.000500000
68    Wet   PK  CCA_Pso 20.8333333 2.000000       0.063000000
82    Wet   DB  CCA_Nma  0.0000000 0.000000       0.000000000
84    Wet   DB  CCA_Pso  2.8333333 8.333333       0.017833333
```

The idea is to plot `NbWB_m2` against `mean_PercentCover` for each Category using a different color for each Category and a different symbol for each Site.

Here is the script:

```
y <-WetNmaPso$NbWB_m2
x <-WetNmaPso$mean_PercentCover
library(ggplot2)
PlotNmaPso<-ggplot(WetNmaPso,aes(x=x,y=y))+
stat_smooth(method="lm",
aes(color=Category))+
geom_point(aes(color=Category,shape=Site))
```

[image: plot1]

Now is my question. How do I make individual plots for each Category and keep the right color and the right symbols? I have tried to use face_wrap but somehow it mixes up my data points. Here is what I have been trying to do:

```
Individual_plots<-PlotNmaPso + facet_wrap(~Category)
```

[image: plot2]

The resulting graph shows two individual graphs for each Category which is good but the data points are not correct and the symbols have been mixed up between the two categories. 
I have tried different things but never got the expected result.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the points did not displayed correctly because you need to insert x and y inside the `geom_point()` function.

For example:

```
ggplot(WetNmaPso) + geom_point(data=WetNmaPso,aes(y=NbWB_m2,x=mean_PercentCover,color=Category,shape=Site,size=7)) + stat_smooth(method="lm",aes(y=NbWB_m2,x=mean_PercentCover,color=Category)) + facet_grid(. ~ Category)
```

[image]

Got the same results with scatterplots in Excel, plotting each category separately.

Comment: Hi, yes, those outputs are the ones I get as well. Unfortunately the second output is not correct, the data points have been mixed up. You can see it by comparing the points to the ones in the first output. For instance, in CCA_PSo, the point located at x=0.063 y=20.83 had a cross as a symbol in the first output (representing the Site PK) but the same point has a full square as symbol in the second output (Site=MP). Other example, the full red square in CCA_Nma has nothing to do in this plot, it should be in CCA_Pso as a diamond. I cant manage to get the right points when splitting the graph.

Comment: @user3013153, I am not sure if understood you. I edited the answer because I had switched the x and y axis. It seems now the legend is the same as the first example (added the argument size to emphasize the styles). Is that it?

Comment: Hi Andre, many thanks for your help, this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet

```
ggplot(WetNmaPso, aes(x=NbWB_m2, y=mean_PercentCover, color=factor(Category))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(Site)), size=5) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", size=1.2)+facet_wrap(~Category) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name="Site") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name="Category")
```

Produces this, which seems like what you want:

[image]

Notes:

1. Your script was failing because you created vectors x and y
   separately. The first call, `ggplot(WetNmaPso,...)` sets WetNmaPso as the default
   dataset. From then on all references within `aes(...)`,  will be to
   columns of WetNmaPso, unless you explicitly specify a new dataset in a
   future call (e.g., `geom_point(data=some.other.df,...)`.
2. Setting `color=factor(Category)` in the first `ggplot(...)` call causes this
   grouping to apply to everything that comes after, unless explicitly
   changed.
3. The last two calls (to `scale_*`) merely change the legend titles.
4. Finally, for whatever its worth, fitting lm to data like this is
   fraught because the points at NbWB_m2 ~ 20 have exceptionally high
   leverage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your notes, it helped me better understand what was wrong in my script. I totally agree with you on the last note, I am aware that fitting lm is not appropriate with my data. I did it to have a quick visual representation. I have read that loess should be more appropriate but don't know yet how to use it. I have an error message when replacing method="lm" by method="loess" in my script so I guess it is more complicated than just changing that. I will read more about it.